# Magento extension upgrade failed due to conflicts with another extension

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, e-commerce

I have installed the extension **market_ready_germany 2.1.40** on magento 1.7. This extension has dependencies with below extensions & are automatically installed along with it.

- Mage_Payone 3.3.11
- Locale_Mage_community_de_DE 1.7.0.0.2
- BankPayment 1.1.0
- symmetrics_trustedrating 0.2.6
- symmetrics_cashticket 0.1.14
- trusted_shops_buyer_protection 0.4.30
- Flagbit_Factfinder 3.3.12

While upgrading "trusted_shops_buyer_protection" extension to its latest version 0.5.4 shows the error:

```
CONNECT ERROR: Package community/trusted_shops_buyer_protection 0.5.4 conflicts with: community/market_ready_germany 2.1.40
```

The upgrade works if "market_ready_germany" extension is uninstalled.

Any solutions to resolve this conflict without uninstalling "market_ready-germany" ?